# Accessibility: How to always set the focus on the navigation item's title view

Tags: ios, accessibility, voiceover, uiaccessibility

I'm using a UINavigationController in my app.
When using VoiceOver the backButton has the focus, when a new ViewController is pushed.

I'd rather have the accessibilityLabel of the titleView been focused if the view appears,
so that its accessibilityLabel is read first.

Using `UIAccessibilityPostNotification(UIAccessibilityScreenChangedNotification, self.navigationItem);`the titleView seems to be focused, when I create and push the view controller for the first time.
But when I come back from another view controller (pushed onto the first one), the focus is on the back button again.

Comment: This is generally how VoiceOver works for navigation controllers. Your users are going to expect this behaviour, are you sure you want to change it?

Comment: I'd probably expect to learn about the content the current screen is actually offering, maybe the navigational "back" is not the most important thing at the beginning?

Comment: Where do you call `UIAccessibilityPostNotification` from? Try calling it from `viewDidAppear:`.

Answer (score 7):

I should've set the the accessibilityLabel of the titleView, not the navigationItem.
The following works:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
{
   ...
   self.navigationItem.titleView.accessibilityLabel = @"[text-to-speak]";
}
- (void) viewDidAppear
{
  [super viewDidAppear];       
  UIAccessibilityPostNotification(UIAccessibilityScreenChangedNotification, self.navigationItem.titleView);
}
```

Comment: does this work when you a returning from a modal view?  I can't get it to NOT go to the back button.  Works fine the first time the screen is displayed, but any subsequent "appears" always go to the back button.